# JPA one to many relationship - @transactional - get children collection

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

I want to get the children collection of the owner entity of a **one to many** relationship.
I have those two entities :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "commande")
public class Commande implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "commande")
@JoinColumn(name= "papa_id")
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Piece> pieces = new HashSet<>();



@Entity
@Table(name = "piece")
public class Piece implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ref")
    private String ref;

    @ManyToOne
    private Commande commande;
```

And the resource :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/papas/{id}",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<Papa> getPapa(@PathVariable Long id) {
    log.debug("REST request to get Papa : {}", id);
    Papa papa = papaRepository.findOne(id);
    papa.getEnfants().size();
    ...
}
```

I had to put **@Transactional** in order to make the .size() work (otherwise I have an exception).
It works.
But if in another method I delete one Enfant entity, then if I call getPapa again, I am getting an error durint .size() :

```
Unable to find com.myapp.stagiaireproject.domain.Enfant with id 3
```

Is it a problem of a transaction not closed?

Answer (score 1):

For the first time, move all work with repository to service and mark this method as @Transactional. Set @Transactional annotation to controller method is bad practice.

One-to-many annotation is lazy by default, you can explicity set `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "commande", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`
to told  hibernate to read collection from database when fetching this entity.

Returning to you question: if you done this is one transaction, hibernate uses fist level cache (wich is not disabled), i.e. it caches entities, which loads by PK (id) during the transaction. And if you moves all work with repository to service class, your transaction commited before you return data from controller, and next request will read data from database, not from cache.

Comment: Ok, thanks, right for the bad pactrice. My application uses second level cache for hibernate. So if I move my code to a service class, the pb will be over?